# Intex Pool Mikveh for Men?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

Does dipping in an [above-ground pool](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what%20is%20an%20intex%20pool&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU15OA9-PqAhXTSxUIHZy9BIQQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1536&bih=775), that sits atop of padding on top of the lawn, satisfy the requirements for a Men’s Mikveh?

Comment: It has to be pure rainwater of 40 se'ah.

Comment: Can you better define what you mean by "the requirements for a Men’s Mikveh"? In most regards, men and women have the same rules regarding mikvaot (Zav is one notable exception)

Comment: It depends on how the water is being put in and handled.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, since men do not have to go to the mikvah at all today and if men want to go its only as a minhag like erev rosh hashana, yom kipper or tifalas keri. The mikvah tha you discribed is a kli and it makes it שאובים.
The Mishina Bruah says in
['סימן פח ס'ק ד](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=60386#p=242&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) that you can use מים שאובים for these kinds of tevilos.

Comment: You may be able to use mayim sheuvim, but how do you know that טבילה בכלי is ok?

Comment: It's also not true that men only go to the mikvah as a minhag.

Comment: where do men go to the mikivah that's not a minhag?

Comment: @Efraym If they wish to ascend Har HaBayit

Comment: Or eat challah in the diaspora @Joel or teruma in the diaspora

Comment: Or because they don't want to be able to metammei a whole bunch of tevel fruit without touching each one @JoelK

Comment: Or to prepare for a holiday @JoelK

Comment: Or because they just want to @JoelK